# What is the ratio of the $(r+1)$st term to the $r$th term in the expansion of $\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)^n$?

Tags: binomial-theorem

What is the ratio of the $(r+1)$st term to the $r$th term in the expansion of $\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)^n$?

It seemed pretty easy and I soon came to the answer $\dfrac{x(n-r)}{2(r+1)}$

However this is wrong, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you mean $(1+x/2)^n$?

Comment: What is correct, then?

Comment: Is $1$ the first term?

Comment: Yeah but how would that change things?

Comment: Is it possible that the term corresponding to $\binom n 0 1^n(x/2)^0$ is considered the first term, and hence $r=1$ for that term?

Comment: By convention the $r^{th}$ term of a polynomial in $x$ is the term involving $x^{r-1}$ , the constant is always called the first term, there is no zeroeth term.

Comment: This is right. Books are written by people, and people can male mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

By the binomial theorem,
$$
\left(1+\frac x2\right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk \left(\frac x2\right)^k.
$$
So for $1\leqslant r\leqslant n-1$ we have the ratio of the coefficient of $\frac x2^{r+1}$ over the coefficienct of $\frac x2^r$ as
$$
\binom n{r+1}/\binom nr = \frac{n!}{(r+1)!(n-r-1)!} \cdot \frac{r!(n-r)!}{n!} = \frac{n-r}{r+1}.
$$